# Location of movies stored in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-location

I have downloaded some movies from the windows store via the Movies and TV app. I would like to know where they are stored. Thank you.

Comment: Search the hard drive for a movie title you have downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages` is the place where Modern UI applications keep their data.